# HTML5 Video tag format

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, progressive-download

So I'm trying to write a server to stream video to a client in html5/javascript, and I'd like to use the already existing framework of the video tag in html5 if that's possible.  That being said, I can't find I good source for what the format of the stream is.  I think it works using progressive downloading (this is how youtube works as well?), but I can't find what the header of any given progressive download packet should look like.

Can someone point me in the direction of some information about the actual format of the video tag stream?  I'm also not 100% devoted to the idea of using the video tag, so if someone has a better alternative, that'd also be great!

Answer (score 0):

You just need an HTTP server such as Apache or Nginx to serve the progressive download of MP4 video files.

Comment: I'd like to essentially implement a server like an extremely lightweight apache that just has video streaming capabilities (e.g. it will only be in the source tag of a video on a webserver hosted elsewhere.)

Comment: If lightweight is an objective, Nginx is more suitable and easier to be customized. Here is the link of the module for mp4 streaming with Nginx. http://h264.code-shop.com/trac

Comment: So would building my own be an enormous undertaking?